# What is The Best Practice to Shutdown GRPC Server Over a Client Command

Tags: grpc

As I understand implementation of a `ServerController` which could stop the server it self as a GRPC Server Service who'd calling a `GracefulStop` is a subject for a DeadLock

- `GracefulStop` waits for all the command to be completed
- The `EndCommand` it self waits for the `GracefulStop` end

So how such a case is to be handled in a common practice? Should another super GRPC server be dedicated for a ServerController it self? Still the same problem to shutdown controller takes the place any way.

So is it possible to stop an GRPC Server from the Client over a command with a success acknowledge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot have a server method that triggers server shutdown with a success acknowledgement. The server only finishes shutting down after there are no more pending requests. The request to shut it down will keep it open, or that request will fail and then the shutdown will complete successfully.

Comment: Oh thanks for a clarification @murgatroid99. And should shutdown initiation at least guarantee no more incoming method requests would be accepted.

Comment: Yes, it should do that.

Comment: So, if I'm using grpc-streaming, and this stream is long-lived (rpc will be active while the client is running), I'll never be able to call Shutdown() on server side, because of deadlock? Can I force cancel all active rpc's on server side to safely call Shutdown()?

Comment: To be clear, the problem here is not just shutting down the server. It's having a remotely callable method on the server that instructs it to shut down *and* waits for that shutdown to complete before responding. That combination results in a deadlock. There is nothing inherently unsafe about shutting down a server while there is a long-lived stream on it. It will just wait for that stream to end. On the other hand, if you do need to cancel all active calls, servers generally have a method to do that. The specific API depends on the language.

Comment: Yep, it's not about just shutting down, but I'm trying to find an answer on my question in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76371924/finishing-active-rpcs-on-server-side-when-signal-is-handled-with-long-lived-grp and did not succeed yet.